# Feasibility of VPN connection using VB6 and RAS API

Tags: winapi, vb6, connectivity

We have a modem terminal application written in VB6. It works great for what we need it to do, but there is a new requirement to initiate a VPN connection when dialing a particular provider. I've looked over some related posts and it looks like this may be possible using the RAS API. Can anyone suggest resources/advice for working with this API beyond MSDN?

Difficulty - .NET is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be as robust as you need, but I have called out to the system rasdial command in the past for simple situations where I needed to setup a VPN connection.

```
USAGE:
        rasdial entryname [username [password|*]] [/DOMAIN:domain]
                [/PHONE:phonenumber] [/CALLBACK:callbacknumber]
                [/PHONEBOOK:phonebookfile] [/PREFIXSUFFIX]

        rasdial [entryname] /DISCONNECT

        rasdial
```

Not industrial strength, but good to use in scripts and such.

Comment: I am sure that someone somewhere has wrapped this API using COM/ActiveX.  Depending on your desire/ability to pay, you could get more control that route.  Otherwise, I think you may be stuck creating your own wrapper from VB.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Is .Net completely not an option or is it not an option to switch everything you have into .Net? You could create a .Net class library and enable COM+ and then use the library in your existing VB6 application.

Apologies if this isn't an option either.

Comment: Solid suggestion, but no .NET at all.

Answer (score 1):

In worse case where you only find .NET examples I would use .NET Reflector to see what APIs the .NET framework is calling and what parameters it is passing. I did this when I was trying to use GDI+ in VB6. A algorithm worked great in .NET but failed badly when I used the direct API in VB6. Using reflector I found the parameter I was messing up and then it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle the interop and understand converting C# to VB6, I have pretty much all of the RAS API completed on my open source project. You could just take the bits and pieces of it out you need and put them in your project. Just check out the source code tab on the project, it's all under there.

http://dotras.codeplex.com

The component you'd be interested in is RasDialer, just be warned that component is pretty complex under the hood.